# SSRS IIF based on parameter value

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS 3.0 and am having troubles changing the font color of a field based on a parameter value and a function.  The divide function does work correctly as it is being used in other parts of the report.

```
=IIF((Code.Divide(Sum(Fields!Total.Value), 
ReportItems!CustTotal.Value) < ReportItems!Textbox39.Value) 
and (Parameters!Filter.Value="A"),"Red","Black")
```

Comment: Are your parameter values hard-coded or retrieved from a query?

Comment: The parameter "filter" is hard coded.  It is a list that the user can choose from to decide which types of formatting they want.